# Get Spotify URI android studio

Tags: java, android, uri, spotify

I want to get a song URI from Spotify via parameters such as song name and artist name.  I've looked through the [Android SDK documentation](https://spotify.github.io/android-sdk/player/) and don't see what I am looking for. I could be wrong though. Currently, the way I get a track playing is by hard coding the URI like this:

```
mPlayer.playUri(null, "spotify:track:5m578MgxuEC956dulprCe8", 0, 0);
```

I want to do something along the lines of this, but am not sure if it is possible:

```
mPlayer.playUri(null, track.getUri, 0, 0);
```

Any ideas on how to achieve what I described above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android you can use [Spotify Web API for Android](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android/) to access the search feature that is a part of [Spotify Web Api](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/).

[searchTracks()](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android/blob/cdf0cd4916e0df8f06d0c9fefb665e2962c0d539/spotify-api/src/main/java/kaaes/spotify/webapi/android/SpotifyService.java#L1484) might be the method you need.

Comment: String songUri = spotify.searchTracks("Stairway to Heaven").tracks.items.get(0).uri; 
I've tried this but doesn't seem to do what I'm looking for. Any advice?

Comment: @user12345642312312143 `songUri` when passed to `mPlayer` should start playback. But you need to make sure that `mPlayer` is created for a premium user and the track you try to play is available in the user's region. 
If you make a Spotify Web API call as an authorized users all results you get should be playable AFAIK.